# pandas-profiling "Duplicate rows" section is not showing-up in the HTML Report

Tags: html, pandas, pandas-profiling, data-profiling

I am using pandas-profiling=2.8.0 and I have generated an HTML report in which 2 duplicates are shown in the Overview Section, as seen below
[image]

But the "**Duplicate rows**" option/section is missing in my HTML Report header.

But in the shared example on the documentation page: https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/examples.html

**You can see that the "Duplicate rows" is present in the official examples report.**

Examples (Census Income Report) : https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/examples/master/census/census_report.html

[image]

Can anyone tell what is missing in my code due to which I am not getting "Duplicate rows" in the HMTL Report header?

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
df = pd.read_csv('items.csv', sep='|')
profile = df.profile_report(title='Data Profiling Report') 
profile = ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_file(output_file='txt_data_profile.html')
```